# What is the better way to retrieve (any) element from a HashSet?

Tags: java, hashset

I'd like to retrieve some element from my HashSet, any would do. Since no simple get method exists, at the moment I use :

```
for (Object o : myHashSet){
    return o;
}
return null;
```

Is there a better way to retrieve just some element from my HashSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an iterator:

```
if (!myHashSet.isEmpty())
    return myHashSet.iterator().next();
return null;
```

or, if you know for sure the `Set` is not empty, simply:

```
return myHashSet.iterator().next();
```